# Mongodb saves list of object

Tags: java, serialization, mongodb

I know how to save a list of String

Now, e.g. I create my own Animal class

But when I try to save list in mongodb, it gives

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class Project

I do create a new mongo collection Animal， but it is still not working.

Comment: mongo stores json (bson actually) not java objects. You probably need to use the java mongo driver to store the data.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out Morphia or similar, where you can create object models and save them directly to Mongo.

http://code.google.com/p/morphia/

Answer (score 1):

If Animal class extend [ReflectionDBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/ReflectionDBObject.html) then you can insert list of Animals.

```
Animal extends ReflectionDBObject {

}
```